# Increase Lines of Scrollback for all sessions quickly

Tags: windows-registry, putty, regedit

I have over 100 PuTTY sessions saved, and I wanted to increase my [Lines of Scrollback](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-scrollback) from 200 to something higher like 5000.

I know how to do this manually, one by one.  However I don't want to spend my whole day doing this, does anyone know how to do it in a faster manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Windows PowerShell run the following command

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\* | foreach-object {set-itemproperty -path $_.pspath -name ScrollbackLines -value "5000"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps:

[image]

The registry location is

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions
```

Don't know how to automate it (yet). Short on time.

Comment: My method for doing it quickly was just to export that portion of the registry, and do a search and replace with a text editor on the .reg file, then re-import.